# insertObjectAtIndex method does not work

Tags: iphone, indexing, nsmutablearray

Assume filteredArray={ 0,2,3,4}. I have another array called tempArray. I want to insert 1 at zeroth,second,third,fourth position in tempArray.
This code snippet is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
// Assume filteredArray={ 0,2,3,4}
for (int i=0 ; i<[filteredArray count] ; i++)
{
    [tempArray insertObject:@"1" atIndex:[filteredArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Comment: insertObject:atIndex: most certainly does work. Accepting 0% answers on SO and expecting helpful responses to vague questions on the other hand...

Comment: you should initialize tempArray using initWithCapacity in this case..

Comment: firstly check NSlog(@"%d",[filteredArray count]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to insert objet to array at index, you must have some ojects (not less then index) in array. In different words, you can't add object at index 5 to array with count 3.
here is solution i advice:

```
 for(int i=0;i<[filteredArray count];i++) { 
[if ([[filteredArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue] == i) [tempArray addObject:@"1"];
else [tempArray addObject:/*any ampty object*/];
 }
```